# IBRK TWS API error() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, tws

If I run a basic TWS example, I receive the error message . If I comment out the `error()` call back it runs fine. I've tried this on several examples and get the same result.

```
    Exception has occurred: TypeError
    
    error() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
    
    File "/Users/jayurbain/Dropbox/twsapi/Algorithmic Trading using Interactive Broker's 
    Python API /ib_basic_app.py", line 20, in <module> app.run()
```

Please advise.

Here's the call back that is being overridden in wrapper.py:

```
    def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str, advancedOrderRejectJson = ""):
```

Here is the entire code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
 
class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)
        
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error {} {} {}".format(reqId,errorCode,errorString))
 
app = TradingApp()      
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)
app.run()
```

Comment: The code as you have presented it does not reproduce the error (when I run it on my machine), so you may need to dig deeper to find the underlying cause.  Have you debugged to look at what variables are correctly/incorrectly being passed to the error function?  What version of ibapi are you using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to execute `python setup install` rather than using `pip` to install ibapi. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

There are breaking API changes in versions starting 10.14.
Since there is another argument for the error callback, you need to include it in args.

```
def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson):
    print("Error {} {} {}".format(reqId,errorCode,errorString))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IBAPI version 1019.01 as well as 1025.01.

I just added a dummy argument to def error() in wrapper.py :

```
def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str, advancedOrderRejectJson = "", arg5 = ""):
```